# What are some popular process models for solving problems utilizing?

Tags: data-mining, data-science-model

What are some standard process models which people or companies use to solve their problems utilizing data? I'm familiar with current process models such as CRISP-DM and SEMMA, but I wondered if there are any other approaches or guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know about CRIPS-DM and SEMMA, you can loo into this too [KDD](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/kdd/1_kdd.html)

[image: KDD]

Comment: Thank you, It's a bit confusing for me, people use Knowledge Discovery in Databases, Data Mining, Data Analysis, Knowledge Extraction as if they are interchangeable words, if  so why there are so many different words are used to refer to the same thing?

Comment: It is depends on your business problem. For example if you are implementing a Genetic Algorithm then KDD is suggestible. All of these words are similar but not same. So you need to dig deep and see which suits your business problem.

Comment: @Toros91 Could you please answer this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33265/what-to-report-in-the-build-model-asses-model-and-evaluate-results-steps-of-cri Thanks.

Comment: @ebrahimi : sure. Would do that in sometime. Came out for lunch.

Comment: @Toros91 Thanks a lot. Really, I read this: https://mineracaodedados.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/the-crisp-dm-model-the-new-blueprint-for-data-mining-shearer-colin.pdf and this: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/modeler/18.0/en/ModelerCRISPDM.pdf but I confused where to report the accuracy measure of cross-validation and the accuracy measure of holdout test data set.